# SUM of DISTINCT in Microsoft Query

Tags: sql, oracle, alias, ms-query, microsoft-query

I have a query that returns data somewhat like this:

```
REF01   10  50  1
REF01   10  50  1
REF01   20  40  1
REF01   20  40  1
REF01   30  30  2
REF02   40  20  1
REF02   50  10  2
REF02   50  10  2
```

And I need it to return it like this:

```
REF01   60  120
REF02   90  30
```

To do so first I add a `DISTINCT` (`GROUP BY` with all the columns also seems to do the same) to remove the duplicates which returns it like this:

```
REF01   10  50  1
REF01   20  40  1
REF01   30  30  2
REF02   40  20  1
REF02   50  10  2
```

And then I need to add a `SUM()` of that result without the removed duplicated ones being counted.

I have tried solutions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30864695) but I get an error with the `FROM (SELECT ...)` and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19323536) which does work except that one of the columns inside the subquery is the result of an operation (`column_1-column_2-column_3`) which causes the error `ORA-00972: identifier is too long` for exceeding the 30 characters maximum limit and trying to apply an alias with `AS` in the subquery (inside the `WITH SUBQUERY AS ( ... )` isn't working in MS Query from what I have tried.

Support for most SQL functions and such isn't the best on Microsoft Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit - This is the solution that worked:**

The issue seems to be related to the auto-generated column names, that end up being too long for oracle. To avoid this problem, the query can explicitly name the CTE columns, as shown below:

```
with
x (col1, col2, col3, col4) as ( -- columns are named here
  select distinct col1, col2, col3, col4 from t
)
select col1, sum(col2), sum(col3)
from x
group by col1
```

**Solution #2 (that didn't work in the tool)**:

If the tool you are using does not have support for subqueries, you can still trick it by creating a view instead. For example:

```
create view view1 as select distinct col1, col2, col3, col4 from t
```

Then, just run a query that uses it:

```
select col1, sum(col2), sum(col3) from view1 group by col1
```

Result:

```
COL1   SUM(COL2)  SUM(COL3)
-----  ---------  ---------
REF02         90         30
REF01         60        120
```

**Solution #3 (that didn't work in the tool either)**:

```
select col1, sum(col2), sum(col3) from (
  select distinct col1, col2, col3, col4 from t
) x
group by col1
```

**Data used for testing:**

For reference, the data script I used is:

```
create table t (
  col1 varchar2(10),
  col2 number(6),
  col3 number(6),
  col4 number(6)
);

insert into t (col1, col2, col3, col4) values ('REF01', 10, 50, 1);
insert into t (col1, col2, col3, col4) values ('REF01', 10, 50, 1);
insert into t (col1, col2, col3, col4) values ('REF01', 20, 40, 1);
insert into t (col1, col2, col3, col4) values ('REF01', 20, 40, 1);
insert into t (col1, col2, col3, col4) values ('REF01', 30, 30, 1);
insert into t (col1, col2, col3, col4) values ('REF02', 40, 20, 1);
insert into t (col1, col2, col3, col4) values ('REF02', 50, 10, 1);
insert into t (col1, col2, col3, col4) values ('REF02', 50, 10, 1);
```

Comment: When I try to do that I get an error saying that it wasn't possible to add the the table '('.

Comment: It must be the tool you are using to create queries.

Comment: In order to produce the result you want, you necessarily need a subquery. If the tool you are using doesn't allow them, you are out of luck.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Query since I need to use it with Microsoft Excel. It does allow subqueries at least using the `WITH subquery_name AS ( subquery )` method but with that way I'm running into the problem described in the question.

Comment: I wrote another solution... using views. Maybe you can try this one.

Comment: Trying to create a view threw the error saying that I don't have enough privileges, possibly since the database that I'm getting the data from is read-only.

Comment: Coming back to your original solution, Oracle is complaining the [automatically] generated column names of the CTE are too long. But those ones are configurable. For example: `WITH x (col1, col2, col3, col4) as (<subquery>)`. Maybe your tool does have an option to specify them. Just a tought.

Comment: Using `WITH x (column aliases) AS ()` did solved the issue! Thank you :)

Comment: I'll accept your answer since your solution in the comment worked. If you can, please edit and add that solution to the answer.

Comment: @user7393973 Solution added.

Answer (score 1):

Seems obvious but would this not work (revised)?

```
 select col1, sum(col2) as col2, sum(col3)  as col3 from 
(Select col1, col2, sum(DISTINCT col3) as col3 from t
group by col1, col2) aa
group by col1
```

or with a WITH:

```
WITH tt as (Select col1, col2, sum(DISTINCT col3) as col3 from t
group by col1, col2) 

select col1, sum(col2) as col2, sum(col3)  as col3 from tt
group by col1
```

Comment: I think this will produce a different result.

Comment: The solution with `SUM(DISTINCT column_name)` seems to work. I'll test it more to see if its getting the correct data.